# Project a rectangular div with text on a cone/cylinder surface

Tags: javascript, html, css, matrix, coordinate-transformation

I have some arbitrary text in a `DIV` of certain height and width. This `DIV` is to be projected onto a solid surface using javascript. Something like `COKE` is slapped on a cylindrical can of soda.

How should I go about it?

Comment: WebGL possibly. Otherwise, HTML/CSS/Javascript isn't going to be enough for this short of building your own renderer.

Comment: @Ouroborus yes, webgl. Create a texture of the text, and mao it on the given surface. Take a look at three.js, for instance.